# How to prove transcendentality of $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

Today I calculated some integral and get $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$, as a result. Then I thought about representing it in the terms of $\pi$, but wolfram told me that this number is transcendental. But how can we show it?

Comment: Even more precisely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#General_rational_argument

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332444/transcendence-of-gamma1-3-gamma1-4), with [answer at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209936/transcendence-of-gamma1-3-gamma1-4).

Comment: "but wolfram told me that this number is transcendental": $\pi$ is transcendental as well, so what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such values of the Gamma function were first proven to be transcendental by Chudnovsky:

Algebraic Independence of Values of Exponential and Elliptic Functions: http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1978.1/Main/icm1978.1.0339.0350.ocr.pdf

Also your wording is strange. $\pi$ by itself is already transcendental so it's strange to say that you can't represent it using the Gamma function.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that $\pi$ isn't transcendental. That was just a prelude.